# Spam filter in R - error in data frame

Tags: r, filter, rstudio, spam, text-mining

I have to build spam or ham filter in R studio. This is my code so far

```
libs <- c("tm", "plyr", "class")
lapply(libs, require, character.only= TRUE)

options(StringsAsFactors = FALSE)

spamOrHam <- c("spam", "ham")
pathname <- ("C:/Users/Edin/Dropbox/FIŠ/2. letnik/Multivariatna analiza/Seminarska/mail")

cleanCorpus <- function(corpus){
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  corpus.tmp <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus.tmp))
  return(corpus.tmp)
}

generateTDM <- function(mail, path){
  m.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s", path, mail)
  m.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = m.dir, encoding = "UTF-8"))
  m.cor.cl <- cleanCorpus(m.cor)
  m.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(m.cor.cl)

  m.tdm <- removeSparseTerms(m.tdm, 0.7)
  result <- list(name = mail, tdm = m.tdm ) 
}

tdm <- lapply(spamOrHam, generateTDM, path = pathname)

bindMailToTDM <- function(tdm){
  m.mat <- t(data.matrix(tdm[["tdm"]]))
  m.df <- as.data.frame(m.mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  m.df <- cbind(m.df, rep(tdm[["HamOrSpam"]], nrow(m.df)))
  colnames(m.df)[n.col(m.df)]  <- "TargetMail"
  return(m.df)
}

MailTDM <- lapply(tdm, bindMailToTDM)
```

When I run `lapply(tdm, bindMailToTDM)` I get an error saying:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 595, 0
```

Any ideas what should I do? I'm doing it by this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/1SaZRg)

And I'm working with those files [goo.gl/DNOA2X](http://goo.gl/DNOA2X)

Comment: We cannot tell without a reproducible example. Show us some data that reproduce your error. In addition, this error is self explanatory: it says your your trying to make a data.frame from objects that don't have the same number of rows. And as it seems one is empty.

Comment: I have 2 folders which contains, one spam mail, and other ham mail. All files are .txt. Code is learning words on which it tries to tell if mail is spam or ham and it learns 1 word for spam and, I think, 13 for ham. I think that this is a problem, but how would I fill empty ones from spam with NA or 0, so it could proceed on?

Comment: Don't know without a reproducible example and data. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question. I don't think anyone will be able to help with this question being as it is. Using lists instead of dataframes would be a solution because you can have different number of rows but still without data I cannot provide code.

Comment: These are the files I'm working with: http://goo.gl/DNOA2X. Just change path in pathname to this directory, and you'll be able to reproduce the error

Comment: add the link to your question. I will be able to help later on but you might get an answer faster.